# Fancybox previous and next links showing up for inline?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm adding fancybox to my site and I'm using inline but the next and previous links are covering the inline content. I don't understand why they would show up at all for inline content.

How do I force the next and previous links to turn off?

Here is an example of the problem:

[Example http://scclib.com/staff/example.png](http://scclib.com/staff/example.png)

My JS Code:
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        'showNavArrows' : false,
        'type' : 'inline'
    });

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable them using the following option :

```
$("selector").fancybox({
    'showNavArrows' : false
});
```

[API & Options docs here](http://fancybox.net/api)

### Update

For FancyBox version 2 and above its :

```
$("selector").fancybox({
    arrows : false
});
```

[Docs for FancyBox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: I added my JS code, but unfortunately the page itself is behind a login.

Comment: I apologize, I found the problem. I had rel="group" in my html which I guess was having it force up the nav. There was no way for you guys to figure that out so technically this was the best answer for my question.

Comment: @Tyler no probs ... at least its fixed :-)

Comment: In fancybox 2 it's just `arrows` (see @dragoon's answer).

Comment: Thanks - That's great for disabling the next/prev buttons but do you know how to disable navigation for keyboard keys?

Comment: @user2737457 try setting `enableKeyboardNav:false`

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK, it doesn't work for me although I should have probably mentioned that I'm using  fancybox 2 if that makes a difference?

Comment: Is this the same in Fancybox 3? I am not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

In **fancybox >= 2.0** it is just

```
$("selector").fancybox({
    arrows : false
});
```